# anonymise xml file in shell with xmllint

Tags: bash, xmllint

First, forgive my english please.
I'm trying to anonymise a xml file in bash, using xmllint and a random value. It works with different xpath and wrinting (like //Prestation/Libelle/@V or //IdVer[text()]), and when there is only 1 appearance of xpath everything is fine and the value is changed.

But since there is at least 2 appearances of the same xpath, he's lost, and he even leaves the loop i guess because the echo only send back 1 value instead of multiple value for the same xpath at different line in the xml file.

Can xmllint deal with more than 1 same xpath ?
Should i use another langage ?

There is the script (it was in french first, so i did my best for you to understand some french sentence, i hope everything would be fine) :

```
#!/bin/bash

#Dir with xml and xhl files
dir="/home/batch_spl_ia/jeremy"

while true; do
    # ask for xpath
    read -p "Enter the xpath (ex: /root/element/@attribut or //Prestation/Libelle/@V or //IdVer[text()]) : " xpath

    # ask how many character for the anonymous value
    read -p "How many character do you want ? : " nb_caracteres

    # ask what type of character
    read -p "Do you want alpha (a), digital (n) or alphanumeric (an)? (a/n/an) : " choice

    # Generate string of characters
    if [ "$choice" == "a" ]; then
        replacement=$(openssl rand -base64 "$nb_caracteres" | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | head -c "$nb_caracteres")
    elif [ "$choice" == "n" ]; then
        replacement=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | head -c "$nb_caracteres")
    else
        replacement=$(openssl rand -base64 "$nb_caracteres" | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c "$nb_caracteres")
    fi

    # Variable to check if a value has been replaced
    value_replaced=false

    # read files in directory
    for file in "$dir"/*.xml "$dir"/*.xhl; do
        if [ -e "$file" ]; then
            # Extract every value for the xpath in file
            orig_value=$(xmllint --xpath "string($xpath)" "$file")
            echo "$orig_value"
            # Check if value has been found for the xpath
            if [ -n "$orig_value" ]; then
                # Replace every appearance of value with the replacement value
                xmllint --shell "$file" << EOF > /dev/null 2>&1
cd $xpath
set $replacement
save
EOF
                value_replaced=true
                echo "value after anonymization : $replacement"
                echo "file anonymized : $file"
            fi
        fi
    done

    # Check if value replaced
    if [ "$value_replaced" = false ]; then
        echo "Error : no value found for the xpath specified : no replacement"
    fi
   
    echo "-----------------------"

    # Ask user if he wants to anonymize another xpath
    read -p "Do you want to anonymize another xpath ?(y/n) : " continuer

    if [ "$continuer" != "y" ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

When i try those 2 xpath the value is changed because there is only 1 xpath in file :
//Prestation/Libelle/@V
//DonneesIndiv/PayeIndivMensuel/Periode/DateDebut/@V

And when i use this xpath the 2 values of the 2 xpath are not changed and the echo only return 1 value instead of 2:
//DonneesIndiv/PayeIndivMensuel/Remuneration/Indemnite/Libelle/@V

Thank you for your understanding and help

Comment: In general, we want a [mre] for a narrow, specific problem -- not your whole script, but the smallest piece that can be broken out from that script that demonstrates the narrow, specific problem that led you to ask a question here when run without changes, with example input, _actual_ output given that input, and _expected_ output given that input. (The more you can hardcode instead of prompting for values, too the better: if a problem depends on what input a user provides, we don't want to need to rely on someone running your code the same way to be able to reproduce the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Find all xpath expression using `whereis` xmllint shell command and change them with another value. Having an array of expressions helps to change all values and save once instead of opening/saving the file for each expression

```
file='tmp.xml'
xpath="//parent/paragraph/@newid"
read -a expr_arr < <(printf "%s\n" "whereis $xpath" "bye" | xmllint --shell tmp.xml | grep -v '^[/] >' | tr '\n' ' ')
replacement="xxxyyyzzz"

declare -a arr

# Iterate over found xpath expressions
for expr in "${expr_arr[@]}"; do

    arr[${#arr[*]}]="cd ${expr}"
    arr[${#arr[*]}]="set $replacement"

    echo "$expr value after anonymization : $replacement"
done

arr[${#arr[*]}]="save"
arr[${#arr[*]}]="bye"

echo "file anonymized : $file"
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | xmllint --shell "$file"

xmllint --xpath "$xpath" "$file"
```

Given this sample

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <parent>
    <paragraph newid="13">Any text</paragraph> 
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <paragraph newid="43">Any text</paragraph> 
    <paragraph newid="as77">Any text</paragraph> 
  </parent>
</root>
```

Ouput showing the used expressions

```
/root/parent[1]/paragraph/@newid value after anonymization : xxxyyyzzz
/root/parent[2]/paragraph[1]/@newid value after anonymization : xxxyyyzzz
/root/parent[2]/paragraph[2]/@newid value after anonymization : xxxyyyzzz
file anonymized : tmp.xml
/ > cd /root/parent[1]/paragraph/@newid
newid > set xxxyyyzzz
newid > cd /root/parent[2]/paragraph[1]/@newid
newid > set xxxyyyzzz
newid > cd /root/parent[2]/paragraph[2]/@newid
newid > set xxxyyyzzz
newid > save
newid > bye
 newid="xxxyyyzzz"
 newid="xxxyyyzzz"
 newid="xxxyyyzzz"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I don't understand eveything about the array part, but about the first answer, it works with your example.

But, when it comes to another example it doesn't work :


```<parent>  
       <paragraph newid="123">Any text</paragraph>  
</parent>  
 <parent>  
       <paragraph newid="456">Any text</paragraph>  
</parent>```  


Same parent but on 2 different level, and same son with 2 differents values

I still have the "<xpath> is a 2 Node Set"
I don't understand how to add a line break sorry

Comment: @Jhilumine updated the answer with a better strategy to find the targets. Should work for any xpath I believe.

Comment: When i use the exact same sample as you did, I only got the "parent 2" and "paragraph 1 and 2" modified. The first value `newid="13"` don't change. When I try with my own file, with a correct xpath (I got the value at the end with the cmd `xmllint --xpath "$xpath" "$file"`), the script returns `XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
//parent/paragraphe[2]/@V: no such node
Entity: line 1: parser error : internal error: detected an error in element content` I tried many xpath and writing but it doesn't work well or returns error

Comment: Questions should always provide a [mcve] so I could try with a representative xml sample including namespaces if any.